# importing sass variables file in Angular components, what's the best way?

Tags: angular

i created a `_var.scss` file in `src/assets` folder, i want to use these variables inside each component in the application, my question is that is it correct to import this file in every component? I feel that i repeat myself when doing it this way, no way to import it in one place only and use it in all components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you **only** `@import` scss variables it will make no harm because in `ng build` they won't be present thanks to preprocessor (well they will be filled where needed).

You should beware putting (@import) global styles. They will be loaded in every component (that imports that) and your css will bloat. You can see that if you `ng build prod` and look into styles for component which included global styles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css custom properties instead of sass-variables.

This way you can access these values in all your  components.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables for examples how to define css custom properties.

Comment: CSS variables are not supported in IE browsers. Ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables.

Comment: If you use these properties only on root-level und you have to support older browsers, there is a polyfill available (bit I havn‘t tested it yet):  https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill